# How do you add two boost any values?

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to be able to add two boost any values as follows:

```
boost::any lAnyVar = 5;
boost::any lAnyVar2 = 5;
boost::any lSum;

lSum = lAnyVar + lAnyVar2;

and

lAnyVar = lAnyVar + lAnyVar2;
```

If the boost any type ids do not match then an exception may be thrown.

Is there something that exists in boost or other to be able to do this?

Comment: I suppose that you are okay with the fact that: given `left = 5;` and `right = 5u;` then an exception will be thrown because `int` and `unsigned int` do not have the same typename ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something that exists in boost or other to be able to do this?

No, because it is very simple to do. `boost::any` was supposed to be generic. For the thing that you need, it would need to implement operator+ for boost::any.